# Loop through array of mp3 filenames and extract id3 tags in to another array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, underscore.js, id3

```
function extractId3(value, index, list) {
  if (path.extname(value) === '.mp3') {
    id3js({ file: '/Users/user/materialApp/client/songs/' + value, type: id3js.OPEN_LOCAL }, function(err, tags) {
      return tags.v2.image;
    });
  }
}

exports.index = function(req, res) {
  fs.readdir('/Users/user/materialApp/client/songs', function(err, files) {
    images = _.map(files, extractId3);
    console.log(images);
    res.json(files);
  });
};
```

I am fairly new to web development and the async nature of nodejs.

I am trying to loop through all the mp3 files that I get after fs.readdir() and extract the id3 tags from them.

The `console.log(images)` produces `[]`.

I am not able to comprehend how to handle the async nature of `id3js()`. What would be the right way to extracting this information and passing it as a response to this http request.

Comment: What does id3js return? I would recommend looking into promises and using those to build up your array

Answer (score 1):

Use Pluck

> **pluck**  _.pluck(list, propertyName)  A convenient version of what is
>   perhaps the most common use-case for map: extracting a list of
>   property values.
>
> var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50},
>   {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
>   _.pluck(stooges, 'name');
>   => ["moe", "larry", "curly"]

```
images = _.pluck(files, extractId3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get it to work was using recursion :

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  var info = new Array();
  fs.readdir('/Users/user/materialApp/client/songs', function(err, files) {
    var mp3s = uscore.filter(files, function(file) { if(path.extname(file) === '.mp3') return file});
    var ID = 0;
    console.log(mp3s.length);
    if (ID < mp3s.length) 
        extractId3(mp3s[ID]);
    else 
        console.log(info);

    function extractId3(file) {
      id3js({ file: '/user/user/materialApp/client/songs/' + file, type: id3js.OPEN_LOCAL }, function(err, tags) {
        if(tags.title) {
          console.log(tags.v1);
          info.push({'file': file, 'title':tags.title, 'album':tags.album, 'year':tags.year});
        }
        ID++;
        if (ID < mp3s.length)
          extractId3(mp3s[ID]);
        else {
          res.json(info);
        }
      });
   }
```